# Restating the subject with "c'est/ce sont"

Tags: grammaire

When must you restate the subject with "c'est/ce sont" ? eg Le plus grand problème, c'est l'argent.

Answer (score 3):

This is used when wanting to put emphasis on the phrase or noun introduced by "c'est."

It's roughly similar to stressing the word in English (or italicizing in written English).

> Money is the biggest problem = L'argent est le plus grand problème
>
> *Money* is the biggest problem = Le plus grand problème, c'est l'argent
>
> Money is the *biggest problem* = L'argent, c'est le problème le plus grand
>
> The biggest problem is money = Le plus grand problème est l'argent
>
> She was the one who wanted to go there = C'était elle qui voulait y aller
>
> *She* was the one who wanted to go there = Celle qui voulait y aller, c'était elle.
>
> She wanted to go there = Elle voulait y aller
>
> She wanted to *go* there = Ce qu'elle voulait faire, c'est y aller
>
> *She* wanted to go there = C'est elle qui voulait y aller / Elle voulait y aller, elle.

Comment: For the last one, one could also say: *c'est elle qui voulait y aller*

Comment: @chqrlie merci, intégré à la réponse

Answer (score 1):

" C'est " est au singulier. Pour la phrase "Le plus grand problème, c'est l'argent", le " l' " est la forme du singulier (le , la ..).

Autre exemple : Ce sont les gens.

Ce sont qui/quoi ? Les gens. Donc vu que "les gens" est au pluriel, on utilise la conjugaison du pluriel.

Avec la question qui/quoi, tu identifies le sujet et conjugue en fonction. :)

Comment: Je pense que son intérêt porte plutôt sur la question de quand utiliser *ce* au lieu de rien. « Le plus grand problème est l'argent » vs. « Le plus grand problème, c'est l'argent »

Comment: De plus la règle présentée dans la réponse n'est pas toujours vraie: *Ceux qui ont raison, c'est nous !* (singulier obligatoire), et *Les plus râleurs, c'est les Français !* (singulier et pluriel tous deux corrects).

Comment: Pour " c'est nous " d'accord, pour "c'est les français" ce n'est pas bon. Ce sont les français. C'est une faute récurrente en France, elle devient même la norme à force de faire cette faute.

Comment: Quand quelque chose devient la norme, ce n'est plus une faute. Toutes les langues se construisent comme-ça. On pourrait d'ailleurs arguer que *ce sont* a dès l'origine été une faute d'accord, *ce* étant un pronom au singulier, il n'y a pas de raison de mettre le verbe qui suit au pluriel de la même façon que *cela sont* est incorrect.

Comment: Néanmoins dire " c'est les français " , reste faux.

Comment: Non, ce n'est pas « faux ». Même l'Académie française ne le considère pas comme tel. Elle recommande le pluriel comme étant « de meilleure langue » à l'écrit mais ne condamne pas le singulier qui est comme je l'ai déjà écrit le temps logique grammaticalement parlant. ***Ce n'est pas les Troyens**, c'est Hector qu'on poursuit* Racine

Comment: En effet, Luke Sawczak, a bien compris ma question. Je voudrais savoir quand, ou si, c'est obligatoire d'employer "ce" (+ être) après le sujet nominal. Ex Le plus grand problème est l'argent. vs Le plus grand problème, c'est l'argent.

Comment: *conjugue* -> *conjugues*

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that adding `"c'"` emphasizes that you are answering the question `"Quel est le le plus grand problème ?"`, either it being a real question or an implicit one. That among several possible problems, you are choosing `"l'argent"` as the main one.

In the specific case of this sentence `"Le plus grand problème, c'est l'argent"` / `"Le plus grand problème est l'argent"`, the difference is negligible, but the version without `"c'"` would be better said reversed: `"L'argent est le plus grand problème"`.

In some other examples, the version without "c'" will not seem correct and you will *need* to reverse it. eg: `"La plus belle, c'est Sarah"`. It does not seem good, to my French ear, to say `"La plus belle est Sarah"`. But indeed, `"Sarah est la plus belle"` is perfectly fine.